# string-join() function throws invalid expression

Tags: xpath, xquery

XPathError
message: "Invalid expression.

`(string-join(/form/Data/MProcess/Process/Id/string(), ','))`

I thought the problem was Process Id was not returning string so I tried string() and text() but they did not work. I can't find the solution.

Here is an example process id: `aee865d1-7253-489c-8d53-2a0d580639d0`

Comment: What is your question? Are closing double-quotes just a typo?

Comment: double-quotes was a typo , sorry about that. My question is what am I doing wrong here, why is this an invalid expression. @JaSON

Comment: I see no errors in your expression. I guess your tool supports [XPath 1.0](https://www.edankert.com/xpathfunctions.html) only while `fn:string-join` is from XPath 2.0

Answer (score 2):

string-join() is an XPath 2.0 function, and many early XPath processors were never upgraded to 2.0. Check what XPath processor you are using and what language level it supports, and upgrade if you can.